# If $ρ_{AB} ∈ D(H_A \otimes H_B)$ such that $ρ_{A}$ is pure. $\implies ρ_{AB} = ρ_{A} \otimes ρ_{B}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Let $H_A, H_B, H_C$ be arbitrary Hilbert spaces.
Let $ρ_{AB} ∈ D(H_A \otimes H_B)$ such that $ρ_{A}$ is pure. Prove that $ρ_{AB} = ρ_{A} \otimes ρ_{B}$
( Hint: One way could be to prove it before for when $ρ_{AB}$ is pure and then use a purification to reduce to this case)

I haven't been able to go very far with this. If $\rho_A$ is pure $\exists$ unit vector $|\psi_A\rangle$ s.t. $ \rho_A =|\psi_A\rangle \langle|\psi_A|$. But I don't know what to do next. How should I go about it?

Comment: The proof of this fact is in von Neumann's Quantum Theory book, chapter 2.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\rho_A$ is pure, there exists a unit vector $|\psi_A\rangle \in H_A$ such that $\rho_A = |\psi_A\rangle\langle\psi_A|$.

Now consider a purification of $\rho_{AB}$, which is a vector $|\psi_{AB C}\rangle \in H_A \otimes H_B \otimes H_C$ such that:

$\text{Tr}_C(|\psi_{AB C}\rangle\langle\psi_{AB C}|) = \rho_{AB}$

By the properties of purification, $|\psi_{AB C}\rangle$ has the form:

$|\psi_{AB C}\rangle = |\psi_A\rangle \otimes |\phi_{B C}\rangle$

Where $|\phi_{B C}\rangle \in H_B \otimes H_C$.

Now we can calculate:

$\rho_{AB} = \text{Tr}_C(|\psi_{AB C}\rangle\langle\psi_{AB C}|) = (|\psi_A\rangle \otimes |\phi_{BC}\rangle)(\langle\psi_A|\otimes\langle\phi_{BC}|) = |\psi_A\rangle\langle\psi_A| \otimes \text{Tr}_C(|\phi_{BC}\rangle\langle\phi_{BC}|) = \rho_A \otimes \rho_B$

Then we conclude $\rho_{AB} = \rho_A \otimes \rho_B$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not understand how you computed $|\psi_{AB C}\rangle = |\psi_A\rangle \otimes |\phi_{B C}\rangle$. What poperties of purification are you using?